# what will I get when I use mallco Scribble with Xcode

Tags: xcode, objective-c-runtime

When I checked the mallco Scribble, and run my code:

```
 __unsafe_unretained UIView *view;
    {
        view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    }
    [view setNeedsLayout];
```

[mallco Scribble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nurFn.png)

I got this error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)
```

But as I know, the address of the released object will fill with 0x55 bytes, but what I got is 0x10.